# Setup Sharekit's share button with UIButton, not UIBarButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, implementation, sharekit

In ShareKit's install instructions here: http://getsharekit.com/install/

they say to create a share button by putting this in the .m

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
 target:self
 action:@selector(share)]
```

How can I set up a share button with just a UIButton, not a UIBarButton?

Answer (score 0):

Create your `UIBUtton` normall.
Then for the `addTarget` method use `share`

so

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(.....
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(share) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```